# Error while using t sql pivot table in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a sql code that runs perfectly on SQL SERVER, it runs fine when I run it in SSRS, but when I substitute my constant value with a variable, it does not return any values.

This is the code I am using.

```
------LISTADO DE calificaciones de ESTUDIANTES
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
  COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast(Codigo as varchar) + ']',
    '[' + cast(Codigo as varchar)+ ']'
  )
FROM RubroCalificaciones
inner join  RubrosMetodosEvaluacion on RubroCalificaciones.IdRubro = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdRubro
inner join MetodosEvaluacion on RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
inner join AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion on AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
where AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdGrupo = @IdGrupo--293856

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
  SELECT *
  FROM (
select Estudiantes.Matricula, Personas.Nombres, Personas.Apellido1, personas.Apellido2,
RubroCalificaciones.Codigo, CalificacionesDetalle.PuntosAsignados
from Matriculas
inner join Personas on Matriculas.IdPersona = Personas.IdPersona
inner join Estudiantes on Matriculas.IdPersona = Estudiantes.IdPersona
inner join AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion on Matriculas.IdGrupo = AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdGrupo
inner join MetodosEvaluacion on AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
inner join RubrosMetodosEvaluacion on MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
inner join RubroCalificaciones on RubroCalificaciones.IdRubro = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdRubro
left outer join CalificacionesDetalle on CalificacionesDetalle.IdRubro = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdRubro and
CalificacionesDetalle.IdMetodoEvaluacion = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
and CalificacionesDetalle.IdMatricula = Matriculas.IdMatricula
where Matriculas.IdGrupo = @IdGrupo--293856

  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
    max(PuntosAsignados)
    FOR Codigo IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your variable into the dynamic SQL.  Also, I rewrote the COALESCE , you only need the column once.

```
CREATE PROC NameThisProcedure
    @IdGrupo int
AS
------LISTADO DE calificaciones de ESTUDIANTES
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
  COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',', '') + '[' + cast(Codigo as varchar)+ ']'
FROM RubroCalificaciones
inner join  RubrosMetodosEvaluacion on RubroCalificaciones.IdRubro = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdRubro
inner join MetodosEvaluacion on RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
inner join AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion on AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
where AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdGrupo = @IdGrupo--293856

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
  SELECT *
  FROM (
select Estudiantes.Matricula, Personas.Nombres, Personas.Apellido1, personas.Apellido2,
RubroCalificaciones.Codigo, CalificacionesDetalle.PuntosAsignados
from Matriculas
inner join Personas on Matriculas.IdPersona = Personas.IdPersona
inner join Estudiantes on Matriculas.IdPersona = Estudiantes.IdPersona
inner join AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion on Matriculas.IdGrupo = AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdGrupo
inner join MetodosEvaluacion on AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
inner join RubrosMetodosEvaluacion on MetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
inner join RubroCalificaciones on RubroCalificaciones.IdRubro = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdRubro
left outer join CalificacionesDetalle on CalificacionesDetalle.IdRubro = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdRubro and
CalificacionesDetalle.IdMetodoEvaluacion = RubrosMetodosEvaluacion.IdMetodoEvaluacion
and CalificacionesDetalle.IdMatricula = Matriculas.IdMatricula
where Matriculas.IdGrupo = @IdGrupo--293856

  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
    max(PuntosAsignados)
    FOR Codigo IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @PivotTableSQL, N'@IdGrupo int', @IdGrupo
GO
```

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic sql?,I have an application that will send the parameter value

Comment: @Carlos, see the bottom of the code.  You have @IdGrupo in the dynamic SQL, and it was given no value. You need to use `sp_ExecuteSQL`, and pass the @IdGrupo value to the dynamic SQL.

Comment: it gives me the same error, it says i need to declare the @IdGrupo... I used the code you rewrote, and I get the same error. I execute the query as Text.

Comment: @Carlos When you use `EXECUTE (@SQL)` that runs in a separate connection. In that connection, your parameters `@IdGrupo` is in the TSQL, but it is not defined.  It is in your stored procedure parameter from SSRS, but needs to be passed on to the connection in EXECUTE/sp_Executesql

Comment: @Carlos is this in a stored procedure or just a block of TSQL directly from SSRS?

Comment: its a block of TSQL directly in SSRS! should I make an Sp?

Comment: I made a sp, and it works but it does not display the columns, and when I run the report I get an error, since I do not get the columns.

Comment: @Carlos - Consider taking this line out from the top bit `where AsignacionesMetodosEvaluacion.IdGrupo = @IdGrupo--293856` because it restricts the columns to only those that the @IdGrupo is involved in.

Comment: yes, Thats because my boss only wants to see a group in specific

Comment: This is a SSRS BUG.  http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/is-this-ssrs-2008-bug--changes-are-not-reflected-in-dataset-3259.shtml

Comment: this is fix with setting the query as text and writing, exec dbo.PivotTable @IdGrupo